# How can I print a bunch of Arcmap mxd's all at once?

Tags: mxd, arcmap, printing, batch

I have a folder with a dozen Arcmap compositions (.mxd files) I need to print. They're all ready to go, I don't need to do any editing. Do I really have to open up each one, wait to refresh, and press print?

Comment: related - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/how-to-batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ArcGIS v10.x

We now [Batch export to PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/how-to-batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-files) and then batch print those via Windows Explorer: *Select PDFs >> Menu >> Print*.

I've notes that say `ArcGISFileHandler.exe /p foobar.mxd` should print but I've not been able to get that to work and I've lost the source reference for that tip; future research for some motivated person perhaps.

#### ArcGIS v9.x

Use `ArcMap.exe /p foobar.mxd` in a batch file. It's a bit quirky and doesn't always work. The most annoying things are a) it ignores the .mxd page size setting and always uses the printers' default page, and b) Addons like MapBook need to be uninstalled or else there will be an error dialog after each .mxd (the map still prints though).

```
@echo off
echo. 
echo. Printing all maps in current directory to default printer 
echo. 
echo  Press [ctrl-break] to abort. 
echo. 
for %%a in (*.mxd) do ( 
  echo.  Processing %%a 
  start /wait C:\path\to\ArcGIS\Bin\ArcMap.exe /p "%%a" 
  )
```

Comment: Ugly but effective - like so much gis stuff :)

Comment: Well the `ArcGISFileHandler.exe` method for v10 doesn't work for me. I keep getting errors about either there being no available ArcInfo licenses available or that Single Use is not authorized. This occurs even when ArcView is the selected level in ArGIS Administrator and Arcmap opens fine via Start Menu etc.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the following utility to be quite helpful.

[THE LOST CARTOGRAPHER](http://lostcartographer.blogspot.com/2008/10/batch-printing-arcmap-mxd-documents.html)

It was written by Ben Slater. In this blog post, he has given the code as well as the executable for Batch Printing ArcMap MXD Documents

Edit: Added more information about the Utility, as per Matt Wilkie's suggestion

Comment: please consider adding a little more description to your answer. For example you give the title of the blog but not the name of the utility or the title of the post introducing it. Links change and move over time and details can help track down the new home.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using COM automation to open the MXD, call the print, and then close the document.
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1170&t=197049

Comment: This answer would be more useful with a small example or an extract of the most important text. The linked resource may not stay in place, especially now that esri is launched a new forums site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the [Print Active View](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002ms000000.htm) sample, but change it so that it uses IMapDocument to retrieve the pagelayout for each mxd.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Print Conductor for Batch Printing documents. I use it daily for my batch PDF Printing work. It  prints all files at once with its  DRAG and Drop feature.  You can just select multiple folders or files and get them printed.

Go to www.print-conductor.com to download the Print-Conductor

Comment: Agree OP you should export all maps in layout view to PDF then just batch print the PDFs. Much better quality as well.