# Batch exporting MXD to PDF files using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, batch, mxd

Nico Burgerhart made a fantastic script called "Batch export MXD to PDF" back in 2008.
    http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14872
    Any ideas how to implement it in ArcGIS 10? Something using Python perhaps? 
    Data Driven Pages does not have anything comparable that i could find.

Here's the steps in read me text file which doesn't jive with ArcGIS 10's new menu bar:

```
Tool: Batch export MXD to PDF
Purpose: Saves all MXDs in the selected directory to PDFs in the selected output folder
Author: Nico Burgerhart (nicoburgerhart@hotmail.com)
Date: 31 Jan. 2007
INSTALLATION NOTES
------------------
1. Open ArcMap
2. Select Tools > Macro's > Visual Basic Editor
3. Select File > Import file
4. Import BatchExportMXDToPDF.bas
5. Select File > Close and Return to ArcMap
6. Select Tools > Macro's > Macro's
7. Select the BatchExportMXDToPDF mactro
8. Click Run
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Export Map Document to PDF is now included in the **[arcpy.mapping module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm)**

Pith of code sample from Esri KB [How To: Export map documents to PDF using Python](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012420):

```
for mxd in mxd_list:

    current_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(ws, mxd))
    pdf_name = mxd[:-4] + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(current_mxd, pdf_name)
```

For a more extended Toolbox example see [Export MXD to PDF](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4ddd1323ae0d4ebe8f8250992faab0f4) courtesy of @bteranUFA

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, lots of good ones there look like.... keep getting **Invalid Mxd filename error** for some reason when using 'Export Map Document to PDF', any ideas?  screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/fOaGp.jpg

Comment: Do you have spaces or special characters in your .mxd?

Comment: yes.... spaces, underscores, and a hyphen. Here's a few examples: `PLR11001200_1101A-BO.mxd`       `1101A_ LT 314.mxd`        `1101A_BB 300B.mxd`       `1101A_BO.mxd`     Do you think i need to take out the spaces and hyphens? i'll give it shot tomorrow morning when i go into work to do some overtime.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz.... It indeed works fine after removing all the spaces, underscores, and hyphens.

Comment: An extra link (@Mapperz's link is not working anymore) : http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012420

Comment: @RobinP thanks for the update, have updated the answer with the link you provided. (esri just need to stop revamping their website and breaking links , like arcscripts)

Comment: Those revamp are terrible for community knowledge. A whole world of arcgis script has disappeared from google.. Seems arscript things have more or less landed here : http://codesharing.arcgis.com/

Comment: I found some things on the codesharing website  : http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4ddd1323ae0d4ebe8f8250992faab0f4 or http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=66ae188d39a74831be74b39c60e0123a

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a VBA module. If you install VBA with ArcGIS 10 you should be able to run it just the same. (VBA is still supported, but will not be in the next release.)
Better approach would be to re-write this as an add-on.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, is there a link with step by step instructions on how to install VBA with ArcGIS 10? any suggestion on how to re-write as an add-on?

Comment: You will need a license file from ESRI and VBA installer is one of the items on the main installation DVD. As for the Add-In (sorry not Add On) there is a bit of  learning curve with VB .NET but it's well worth the effort. Here is a link for the walkthrough: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/

Answer (score 1):

Add the script to a toolbox, then setup two paramters by right clicking on the script tool and typing in the display named like below image and picking data type of folder like in below image:
[image]

```py
#Export a folder of maps to PDFs at their Map Document set sizes
#Written using ArcGIS 10 and Python 2.6.5
#by: Guest

import arcpy, os

#Read input parameter from user.
path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Write MXD names in folder to txt log file.
writeLog=open(path+"\FileListLog.txt","w")
for fileName in os.listdir(path):
    fullPath = os.path.join(path, fileName)
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullPath)
        if extension == ".mxd":
            writeLog.write(fullPath+"\n")
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
            print fileName + "\n"
del mxd
print "Done"
writeLog.close()


exportPath =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
MXDread=open(path+"\FileListLog.txt","r")
for line in MXDread:
    #Strip newline from line.
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    if os.path.isfile(line):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(line)
        newName=basename.split('\\')[-1]
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
            print "Basename:" +newName
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(line)
            newPDF=exportPath+"\\"+newName+".pdf"
            print newPDF
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,newPDF)
            print line + "Export Done"
MXDread.close()
item=path+"\FileListLog.txt"
os.remove(item)
del mxd
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in [this set of GP tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=A910AB18-1422-2418-3418-3885D388EF60) on the ESRI Resource Center, there may be something in there for exporting to PDF in batch.

Comment: like minds - same link as me.

Comment: Thanks Chad, i keep getting Invalid Mxd filename error for some reason when using 'Export Map Document to PDF', any ideas? screen shot: i.imgur.com/fOaGp.jpg

Comment: @Mapperz - D'OH! My mistake!

Comment: keep getting Invalid Mxd filename error when using 'Export Map Document to PDF', any ideas? screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/fOaGp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Building on the contributions of [@Guest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76117/108) and @bteranUFA I've put together a python script and toolbox. It exports all MXD from an input folder to an output location.

From [here](https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/tree/master/ArcToolbox) download `ArcPlus.tbx` and `Scripts\ExportFolder2PDF.py` and save somewhere useful, then read the [usage notes](https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/blob/master/ArcToolbox/Scripts/ExportFolder2PDF.md) if needed.