# How to batch open and export to PDF folder of map packages (*.mpk)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-package

I have a directory full of ArcGIS map package files (mpk) that I need to export to pdf. Is it possible to automate it so I don't have to open and export each one manually?

I need to open each map package, switch to layout view, export to pdf, close it, and repeat with the next map package file.

Comment: Does [the help] (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-tool). It batch prints MXD's located in a common directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Export Package](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000vq000000) tool from the Data Management toolset to perform the unpacking in a Python script.  Once unpacked the comment by @dchaboya should make the rest straightforward.