# Exporting 60 PDF files from each MXD in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, pdf

I need to export 60 PDFs files so I am thinking if there is a way around to export 60 without having to open each MXD file at a time ?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1  Build 3143 .

Comment: So you have 60 mxds that each need to export 1 pdf?

Comment: this might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-tool

Comment: Yes, Craig. There are 4 themes I worked on T factor, K factor, WEI and WEI and their extent location is by county.

Comment: and the mxds are in a folder for each of them. I was wondering if I could do that ?