# Batch exporting individual MXDs to individual PDF files using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, batch, mxd

I need to pdf several mxds into their individual pdfs and am hoping there is a quicker way to accomplish that other than opening each file individually and exporting individually. Data Driven Pages is not an option as it will not work for what I am doing.

I found this question already asked here and downloaded the toolbox and script that matt wilkie shared but it is not working for me: [Batch exporting MXD to PDF files using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/how-to-batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-files)
With the original I was getting an "Error 000576: Script associated with this tool does not exist." Then I copied the script the link above takes you to and put it in a new notepad text file and did "Add Script" to the toolbox. After doing that I quit getting an "error" message. However, it runs and says it is done but there are no pdf files to be found.
The first message is: "Executing: ExportFolder2PDF "input folder name" output folder name false"

Here is the script file with a couple modifications I made:

'''
Export a folder of maps to PDFs at their Map Document set sizes
Known to work ArcGIS 10.4.1 and Python 2.7.3
Adapted from work by @bteranUFA and @Guest
[Batch exporting MXD to PDF files using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/how-to-batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-files)
License X/MIT; (c) 2017 Environment Yukon, Matt Wilkie
'''

```
import os
import glob
import arcpy

# Folder to look for MXDs in
in_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# Where to save output documents
exportPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if exportPath == '':
    exportPath = in_path

overwrite = arcpy.GetParameter(2)
arcpy.AddMessage('Overwrite: %s' % overwrite)

# Set the PDF parameters as variables here:
data_frame = 'PAGE_LAYOUT'
df_export_width = 1920
df_export_height = 1200
resolution = '300'
image_quality = 'BEST'
colorspace = 'RGB'
compress_vectors = 'True'
image_compression = 'ADAPTIVE'
picture_symbol = 'VECTORIZE_BITMAP'
convert_markers = 'False'
embed_fonts = 'True'
layers_attributes = 'LAYERS_ONLY'
georef_info = 'True'
jpeg_compression_quality = 85

maps = glob.glob(os.path.join(in_path, '*.mxd'))

def exportmap(mxdPath, exportPath):
    fname = os.path.split(mxdPath)[1]
    basename = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
    newPDF = os.path.join(exportPath, basename + '.pdf')
    open(newPDF, 'w').close()

    arcpy.AddMessage('Reading: ' + m)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(m)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Writing: ' + newPDF)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, newPDF, data_frame, df_export_width, df_export_height, resolution, image_quality,
                              colorspace, compress_vectors, image_compression, picture_symbol, convert_markers, embed_fonts,
                              layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality)
    del mxd
    return

for m in maps:
    fname = os.path.split(m)[1]
    basename = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
    newPDF = os.path.join(exportPath, basename + '.pdf')
    arcpy.AddMessage('--- %s' % os.path.split(m)[1])

    if os.path.exists(newPDF):
        if overwrite == True:
            exportmap(m, newPDF)
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage('Skipping %s' % newPDF)


arcpy.GetMessages()
```

The original I used was this, the only reason I modified was to see if I could play around with it and get it to work for me:

'''
Export a folder of maps to PDFs at their Map Document set sizes
Known to work ArcGIS 10.4.1 and Python 2.7.3
Adapted from work by @bteranUFA and @Guest
[Batch exporting MXD to PDF files using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/how-to-batch-export-mxd-to-pdf-files)
License X/MIT; (c) 2017 Environment Yukon, Matt Wilkie
'''

```
import os
import glob
import arcpy

# Folder to look for MXDs in
in_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# Where to save output documents
exportPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if exportPath == '':
    exportPath = in_path

overwrite = arcpy.GetParameter(2)
arcpy.AddMessage('Overwrite: %s' % overwrite)

# Set the PDF parameters as variables here:
data_frame = 'PAGE_LAYOUT'  # PAGE_LAYOUT or dataframe name
df_export_width = 1920      # ignored when using PAGE_LAYOUT
df_export_height = 1200
resolution = '300'
image_quality = 'BEST'      # FASTEST, FASTER, NORMAL, BETTER, BEST
colorspace = 'RGB'          # RGB, CMYK
compress_vectors = 'True'
image_compression = 'ADAPTIVE'      # ADAPTIVE, JPEG, DEFLATE, LZW, RLE, NONE
picture_symbol = 'VECTORIZE_BITMAP' # RASTERIZE_BITMAP, RASTERIZE_PICTURE, VECTORIZE_BITMAP
convert_markers = 'False'
embed_fonts = 'True'
layers_attributes = 'LAYERS_ONLY'   # LAYERS_ONLY, LAYERS_AND_ATTRIBUTES, NONE
georef_info = 'True'
jpeg_compression_quality = 85

maps = glob.glob(os.path.join(in_path, '*.mxd'))

def exportmap(mxdPath, exportPath):
    fname = os.path.split(mxdPath)[1]                    # ''some_map.mxd' - discard prefix path elements
    basename = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]                # 'some_map' - discard extension
    newPDF = os.path.join(exportPath, basename + '.pdf') # 'Y:\output\some_map.pdf'
    open(newPDF, 'w').close()   # create empty marker file , for parallel script running.

    arcpy.AddMessage('Reading: ' + m)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(m)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Writing: ' + newPDF)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, newPDF, data_frame, df_export_width, df_export_height, resolution, image_quality,
                              colorspace, compress_vectors, image_compression, picture_symbol, convert_markers, embed_fonts,
                              layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality)
    del mxd
    return

for m in maps:
    fname = os.path.split(m)[1]                          # ''some_map.mxd' - discard prefix path elements
    basename = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]                # 'some_map' - discard extension
    newPDF = os.path.join(exportPath, basename + '.pdf') # 'Y:\output\some_map.pdf'
    arcpy.AddMessage('--- %s' % os.path.split(m)[1])

    if os.path.exists(newPDF):
        if overwrite == True:
            exportmap(m, newPDF)
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage('Skipping %s' % newPDF)


arcpy.GetMessages()
```

After copying and pasting those scripts and looking at how the preview of my question looks I am sure I did not paste them in properly (I am seriously not savvy with scripts and coding at all and quite literally need my hand held, sorry).

I am hoping there is perhaps an updated toolbox/script that will allow me to export an entire folder of mxds into individual pdfs?

I did try to use the [Export MXD to PDF (Python Script & Toolbox Tool)](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4ddd1323ae0d4ebe8f8250992faab0f4) from Esri as well but did not have any luck with it either. It asks for a folder but when you go to choose a folder it actually wants you to choose a single file which is not what I want to do. I do not have the knowledge to run it as a "batch script in toolbox" as Esri suggests in the link.

I am running ArcMap 10.7 and have a Basic license.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to:

1. Create a python list of mxds. Copy/paste each mxd full path into the list. ArcCatalog is good for this.

[image]

2. Export maps as described in the [esri technical support](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012420).

Example:

```
import arcpy, os

#list of mxds
mxd_list = [r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Example\Example.mxd",
            r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Example\Example2.mxd",
            r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Example\Example3.mxd"]
#iterate list
for mxd in mxd_list:
    #map documoent object
    current_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument (mxd)
    #out PDF name
    pdf_name = mxd[:-4] + ".pdf"
    #export map
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(current_mxd, pdf_name)
    print os.path.basename (pdf_name)
```

Comment: I came across a suggestion on a different post (after I posted my question) that it may be due to the file names having special characters? My file names have numbers, letters, dashes, and underscores. I might give your suggestion a try if we can't figure this out. The problem is I typically have anywhere from 20 to around 100 individual mxds to pdf so the folder option really is ideal if it is possible. Thank you!